# How to activate function when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to activate this function,

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 65){
        $('#test').click();
    }
});
```

when this checkbook is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="keyboard">
```

Sorry if this question is already exist.

Comment: Activating which function?

Comment: You can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358673/javascript-checkbox-onchange and model your code like that.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are wanting to have happen

Answer (score 5):

you can use this.

```
$("#keyboard").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    //your function goes here
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to detail your answer, in order to educate the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Check is your checkbox checked inside that function. For example, one of way is to do it this way

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 65 && $('#keyboard:checked').length > 0){
        $('#test').click();
    }
});
```

This statement

```
$('#keyboard:checked').length > 0
```

checks whether there is more than 0 elements with id keyboard that are checked. You can also check using == 1. Other way is

```
$('#keyboard').prop('checked') == true
```

this is written in different manner, but works all the same.