# How to assign another value to a variable using js based swtich

Tags: javascript

I need it to change link6/linkr/linkd to "t" using switch based on "checked", switch is working visual correctly but it doesn`t change link6 to "t"

Anyway switch doesn`t change links to "t"

Using debugger i find out that it doesn`t want to trigger, help me make it triggerable

````
var link6 = "r";
var linkr = "r";
var linkd = "r";

    function download74() {
document.getElementById('link1' + link6).click();
}   
function download143() {
document.getElementById('link2' + linkr).click();
}
    function download198() {
document.getElementById('link3' + linkd).click();
}
function myFunction74() {
  if (confirm("Вы собираетесь скачать 74 devblog (RustUP)!")) {
    download74();
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
function myFunction143() {
  if (confirm("Вы собираетесь скачать 143 devblog (Immortal)!")) {
    download143();
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
function myFunction198() {
  if (confirm("Вы собираетесь скачать 198 devblog (TRINITY)!")) {
    download198();
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

var value = 0;
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
    checkbox1.checked = value;
    document.getElementById("checkbox1").addEventListener("change", function(element){
            if (element.checked) {
      link6 = "t";
    } else {
      link6 = "r";
    }
    });
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
    checkbox2.checked = value;
    debugger;
    document.getElementById("checkbox2").addEventListener("change", function(element){
            if (element.checked) {
            conslose.log("works");
            linkr = "t";
    } else {
    console.log("dont");
      linkr = "r";
    }
    });
    var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("checkbox3");
    checkbox3.checked = value;
    document.getElementById("checkbox3").addEventListener("change", function(element){
            if (element.checked) {
            linkd = "t";
    } else {
      linkd = "r";
    }
    });
    ```
````

Comment: please provide your code, at least a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an example. Take a look if works for you:

```
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
checkbox2.checked = value;

checkbox2.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
   linkr = "t";
  } else {
    linkr = "r";
  }
})
```

Comment: i just made it "onclick' in the html file and it works

Answer (score 0):

You are using "if (checkbox1.checked)" in your anonymous change function, but when this code is triggered, the checkbox1 element no longer exists. You need to do "if (this.checked)" or "if (element.checked)" .

Comment: `      if (this.checked) {
      link6 = "t";
    } else {
      link6 = "r";
    }`
doesn`t work too

Comment: have you put a "DEBUGGER" to check if the function is triggered?

Comment: it doesn`t trigger

Comment: So you have other problem. The variable checkbox1 is found? Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358673/javascript-checkbox-onchange